# How should I find a past date in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c

How can I get a past date in objective C? Like,

```
NSDate *pastDate = //some date 2 weeks ago
```

Answer (score 6):

Off of top of my head:

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *dc = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
[dc setDay:-14];
NSCalendar *cal = [[[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar] autorelease];
NSDate *pastDate = [cal dateByAddingComponents:dc toDate:today  options:0];
```

Answer (score 3):

```
NSDate *today = [NSDate date];
NSLog(@"today:    %@",today);

NSDateComponents *dateComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[dateComponents setWeek:-2];
NSCalendar *currentCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
NSDate *pastDate = [currentCalendar dateByAddingComponents:dateComponents toDate:today  options:0];
NSLog(@"pastDate: %@",pastDate);
```

NSLog output:

```
today:    2011-12-07 11:52:15 +0000
pastDate: 2011-11-23 11:52:15 +0000
```

This example used ARC.

Answer (score -1):

Assume you don't care about DST,

```
NSDate* pastDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-2*7*24*60*60];

// Get the date which is exactly 2 weeks (14 days) ago.
```

Comment: Hope there is no daylight savings time change. :-) It is really best to use `NSDateComponents` and `NSCalendar` and let Apple handle all the corner cases.